# Android generate xml elements based on array

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In WPF we can define an array and bind it to our xml. Elements are then automatically generated based on the contents of this array.:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        this.DataContext = this;
    } 

    ObservableCollection<int> sampleData = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    public ObservableCollection<int> SampleData {
        get {
            if (sampleData.Count <= 0) {
                sampleData.Add(1);
                sampleData.Add(2);
                sampleData.Add(3);
                sampleData.Add(4);
            }
            return sampleData;
        }
    }
}


<Window x:Class="Sandbox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SampleData}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Is something like this **possible** in android?

Comment: @Vanna will look into it. I didnt even know what to search for but that definately is a nice start.

Comment: @Vanna do you mean this? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an XML file, in `res/values/strings.xml`, to define your array member using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

[More about array resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals)

Then receive using

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

But there is no

> automatically generated based on the contents of this array

similar method in Android. To do it you will need to implement an `ArrayAdapter`.

[More about ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Comment: Great answer. I also liked the comments.